# Javascript - regex to check if user write correct formated input

Tags: javascript, regex

in my CLI users can specify what they want to use:
A user command can look like this:

```
include=name1,name2,name3
category=name1,name2
category=name1
```

In another words, a command always consists of 3 parts:

1. command name: can be just `include` or `category`
2. `=`: is in every command
3. name or names of things they want to use, split by `,`

How can I test this to get always true but false on everything else.

I am really bad in regex but I tried something like this:

```
/\category|include=\w/.test(str);
```

to simply test, at least, the most easy alternative which would be `category=name1` but without success.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right path. Here's a fixed regex:

```
/^(category|include)=\w+(,\w+)*$/.test(str);
```

Note:

- the parens around the alternative parts
- the `+` after the `\w` so that you can have several characters
- the optional `(,\w+)*`
- the start and end of string marks (`^` and `$`) in order to check the whole string

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for your requorement:

```
/^(category|include)=(\w+(?:,\w+)*)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU3qI2/1)

`\w+(?:,\w+)*)` in the value part after `=` will allow 1 or more of comma separated words.

Comment: Hard to pick right answer in this, I decided from my subjective point for @Denys one because it looks more readable for me. However thumb for this answer and thanks for answer

Comment: I don't like to post duplicate answer but keeping this because other answer wasn't correct originally (it was edited later to make it working)